# Is there a way to take a JSON object from a table and expand values out into individual columns using SQL(Snowflake)/Python?

Tags: python, json, loops, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Lets say I have the following table with properties, property_address and property_revenue all of type VARIANT:

| ID | properties | property_address | property_revenue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | {...} | {...} | {...} |
| 2 | {...} | {...} | {...} |

An example of a value in the properties column could be:

```json
{
"address": {
    "value": "123 ABC"
  },
  "revenue": {
    "value": 1000000
  }
}
```

and for example the property_adress column for that row would only contain

```json
{
    "value": "123 ABC"
}
```

What would be the easiest way to extract the data and create a table where only the "value" is displayed given the fact there are hundreds of these columns?

[image: table]

One possible idea I had was to use `flatten()` on the properties column in some shape or form but I'm not sure how I would go about doing that. Another way was to use python to loop across each column and then build an SQL query off of that. Do you guys have any suggestions?

Comment: Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72732684/how-to-flatten-a-json-in-snowflake-sql) from @Lukasz, which looks relevant to your use-case. Does your property column has all values and you plan on using only that column to extract values and create columns?

Answer (score 0):

You want to use LATERAL and FLATTEN for this:
https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-To-Lateral-Join-Tutorial

There are some other tutorial references where you can generate view definitions based on the JSON data - this derivative approach can be used to generate column headers from a dynamic query:
https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Automating-Snowflake-Semi-Structured-JSON-Data-Handling-part-2

Comment: I looked into that but every implementation I saw seemed to manually list out every single JSON key to display which is something I want to avoid. I could be looking at the wrong resources, but I'm not sure how I could use flatten to create columns with the name of the JSON key and which contains the values

Comment: You want the query to automatically provide the key as a column header, and the associated paired value as a result?

Comment: Exactly, sorry if I wasn't clear enogh. I'm relatively new to SQL so I'm not sure how feasible something like that would be, although I do think I could do it in python.

Comment: See my edited post above - there's a link to a blog where they explain how to script out a view definition for JSON data.  Same approach applies for generating a query that uses the keys to name the column headers via dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 0):

FLATTEN to turn arrays into rows. OR object members into rows.

What your data appears to be showing a is a couple nested objects. If the objects are consistent, you should just unpack them.

Which I see in the comments you, do not want to do.

I see this a lot recently, and find it strange. I will reframe this another way. A structured database has structure because the structure meets the needs of the problem being solved. And yet you would like to have your needs meet for the problem you would like to solve but you don't want define the structure of you data.